# Windows 7 - BSOD during booting

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard, bsod

I sent my notebook Asus n50vc to repair, i kept my HDD. Now, my notebook is back, so I plugged the HDD back and when I turn the notebook on, it boots my Windows 7, shows Windows logo and then crashes with BSOD.

I think, that they put new motherboard in my notebook so there could be some conflict with drivers. I can't even boot into safe mode, is there any way to fix this problem. (HDD is working properly, I had it in the external box and connected it via USB, no problems with data)

Comment: Wow, I fixed it! I went to BIOS and did something like Advanced -> IDE configuration -> here I changed mode co Comatible from Enhanced. It's working now!

Comment: You should post that as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I went into the BIOS and did something like:

1. Advanced
2. IDE Configuration
3. Changed the mode from Enhanced to Compatible.

It's working now.